# Implementing flatMap on aggregate monad

Tags: scala, haskell, monads, scala-breeze

I'm looking to implement a version of Generator combinators (e.g. analogous to those in ScalaCheck or Haskell's QuickCheck), in which a Generator contains an instance of Rand, a monad representing a probability distribution (taken from the breeze library). Since it is a monad, Rand implements map and flatMap. As is common, I also want to implement Gen as a monad. As shown below, the implementation of map for Gen is straightforward:

```
// Rand is from the breeze library
trait Rand[T] {
    def map[U](f: T => U): Rand[U]
    def flatMap[U](f: T => Rand[U]): Rand[U]
}

case class Gen[T](dist: Rand[T]) {
  def map[U](f: T => U): Gen[U] = Gen(dist.map { f })

  def flatMap[U](f: T => Gen[U]): Gen[U] = {
    // How to implement this?
  }
}
```

However, it is not clear to me how flatMap should be implemented. Is this easily achieved, or does it (for example) require a level of indirection via some intermediate datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible implementation could be

```
def flatMap[U](f: T => Gen[U]): Gen[U] = 
  Gen (dist.flatMap {f(_).dist})
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the intended semantics of `Gen` something like the following?

```
val UnfairCoin = Gen(Rand(Heads -> 0.9, Tails -> 0.1))
val UnfairDieHi = Gen(Rand(1 -> 0.0, 2 -> 0.0, 3 -> 0.0, 4 -> 0.0, 5 -> 0.5. 6 -> 0.5))
val UnfairDieLo = Gen(Rand(1 -> 0.25, 2 -> 0.25, 3 -> 0.25, 4 -> 0.25, 5 -> 0.0, 6 -> 0.0))

def headsHiTailsLo(coinFlip: CoinFlip) = coinFlip match {
  case Heads => UnfairDieHi
  case Tails => UnfairDieLo
}

val flipAndRoll = UnfairCoin flatMap { headsHighTailsLo _ }
```

where:

```
flipAndRoll == Gen(1 -> 0.025, 2 -> 0.025, 3 -> 0.025, 4 -> 0.025, 5 -> 0.45, 5 -> 0.45)
```

If that's right, then the output of `Gen.flatMap` will either need to generate two random samples, one from each distribution, or `Rand` must provide a way to calculate the joint distribution and project it to `U`.

I took a quick look at the documentation for [`Rand.flatMap`](http://www.scalanlp.org/api/breeze/#breeze.stats.distributions.Rand), and it appears that it generates a `Rand` that does the two consecutive random samples, although it's not entirely clear. If that's right, then [chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36532580/1393162) is your winner.

If the two random variables are not independent, then you might have some work to do.

Comment: Fortunately, independence is the desired property.